# Why do leaves of trees shudder when they expose to heavy smoke?

Tags: thermodynamics, biology

Why do leaves of trees shudder when they expose to heavy smoke?

See this video here: https://i.imgur.com/hTOOxu6.mp4

Answer (score 1):

It might be due to the updraft ( upward force ) of the smoke. The smoke itself is traveling upward lifting the branches, while the branches not wanting to be stretched are forced back down by the elasticity of the tree i.e. the branches don’t like being bent so they force themselves back down. So you have two opposing forces one lifting the branches up and one forcing them back down, so you see this shuddering effect. Hope this is what you meant.